# Crystal Report : Unable to Publish as Webservice VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

Am trying to publish a crystal report as a webservice, Have imported rpt into my Web Project.
But when I right click the RPT to publish it as a webservice, I cannot see any option like that.

Am using Crystal Reports 2008 
and Visual Studio 2010
.Net 3.5

Am I missing any configurations?

Answer (score 0):

A Crystal Report file cannot be published as a webservice.  You can use a webservice to retrieve report files for binding to a report viewer but not to access/display the report.